# How to show dialog 2 after a click in dialog 1?

Tags: android

I'm Making my app in Android Studio and I need to make a first custom dialog, press a button inside my dialog 1 and then, dialog 2 should show.
Example:
User presses one button in activity, it appears dialog 1, user presses the "Next" button inside the dialog 1 and then Dialog 2 appears.

The easiest thing that I can think of to do this, is to show the dialog 1, then, after pressing the next button (inside onClick method) dismiss the dialog 1 and then show the dialog 2.
I'ts a bit hard because I'm doing this in a DialogFragment inside of another Activity Fragment.

```
ImageButton NextB = view.findViewById(R.id.NextBN);
NextB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NewDTask();
        }
    });

public void NewDTask()
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.dismiss();
    NewTaskDialog NTD = new NewTaskDialog();
    NTD.show(getFragmentManager(), "New task dialog");
}
```

At this moment, the only thing that happens is that the Dialog 2 shows after pressing next button, but not properly, it blocks the screen and dialog 1 is still there, but blocked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently creating new Dialog 1 and dismissing it in your `NewDTask`. Instead you have to write just `dismiss()` after calling `NewDTask()` from `onClickListener`

```
ImageButton NextB = view.findViewById(R.id.NextBN);
NextB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NewDTask();
            dismiss();
        }
    });

public void NewDTask()
{
  //  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
   // dialog.dismiss();
    NewTaskDialog NTD = new NewTaskDialog();
    NTD.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "New task dialog");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it Works like 50%, the dialog is dismissed but the second dialog doesn't show, it just turns the screen darker. I think it is related with a warning that I have in the line NTD.show(getFragmentManager(), "New task dialog"); Its says that the method getFragmentManager might be null

Comment: Use `getChildFragmentManager()` to show Second Dialog

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class FirstDialog extends DialogFragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_first,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ImageButton nextDialog = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.nextDialog);
    nextDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openNextDialog();
        }
    });
}

private void openNextDialog() {
    SecondDialog dialog = new SecondDialog();
    this.dismiss();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"second fragment");
}
```

}

You can try like this. I opened the first dialog from button click inside another fragment. In Your method You are creating new Dialog and then dismissing the created dialog and not the one you want to dismiss.